# how do i update variables using functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

So heres my code,how are variables being updated as it is not working.What am i doing here?

```
var myNum = 0;

function upVar(eletoup) 
{

    this.eletoup = eletoup;

    this.updateValue=function updateValue(newValue) {
        this.eletoup += newValue;
    }}

upVar(myNum).updateValue(1000);

console.log(myNum)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry but i cant figure how it works..

Comment: Is this the whole code?

Comment: Yup it is... and it wont work

Comment: can you tell what do you want to have as a result?

Comment: There are several fairly basic issues above. I recommend you step back from what you're currently doing and work through some basic JavaScript tutorials and/or a solid "beginning JavaScript" book.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is pass-by-value. That means that when you do this:

```
upVar(myNum).updateValue(1000);
```

`upVar` receives the **value** that `myNum` contains at that moment, not some kind of reference to `myNum`. There is nothing that `upVar` can do with the parameter it receives that value in (`eletoup`) that will change the value of the `upVar` variable. There's simply no connection between them at all.

Instead, the usual thing to do is to have a function that needs to provide an updated value *return* the value, and have the call receive the update from the function. Simpler example:

```js
function updateValue(value, update) {
    return value + update;
}
var myNum = 0;
myNum = updateValue(myNum, 1000);
console.log(myNum);
myNum = updateValue(myNum, 1000);
console.log(myNum);
```

You seem to want to use an object in your code, though. Note that the `this` value that `upVar` receives when you call it the way you are will be the *default* `this` value. In "loose" (aka "sloppy") mode, that default value is a reference to the global object (also available as `window` on browsers). In "strict" mode, it's `undefined`.

You can certainly create an object, initialize a property on it from `myNum`, and then update that *property*. Here's one way to do that:

```js
function upVar(initialValue) {
    return {
        value: initialValue,
        updateValue: function(update) {
            this.value += update;
        }
    };
}

var myNum = 0;
var obj = upVar(myNum);
obj.updateValue(1000);
console.log("obj.value", obj.value);
obj.updateValue(1000);
console.log("obj.value", obj.value);

// Note that myNum isn't changed
console.log("myNum", myNum);
```

There are situations where functions can update variables **not** by receiving them as parameters, but because they *close over* the variable. Those functions are called "closures."

I suggest working through some basic JavaScript tutorials and/or a solid "Beginning JavaScript" book to get a good foundation in how the language works.